# Why can't MANIFEST.MF see packages from Maven's pom?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, osgi, equinox

So I have something like this in my POM:

```xml
<dependency>
  <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

which fetches `jsoup-1.7.1.jar` from maven repo somewhere and places it in my *Maven Dependencies* folder.

Now I can use it in my code (Eclipse doesn't complain), but when I try to put a dependency on it in my `MANIFEST.MF` file:

```
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework, org.jsoup, org.jsoup.nodes
```

Eclipse keeps complaining that:

```
No available bundle exports package 'org.jsoup.nodes'
No available bundle exports package 'org.jsoup'
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? (I'm curious as to the process that goes on in determining what `MANIFEST.MF` sees)

Answer (score 2):

When you work with the eclipse PDE you have to create a target platform that contains all necessary bundles. The normal dependency resolution is not coupled with the target platform. So you have to add each dependency to the to the maven pom and to the target platform.

Btw. if you are working on a server based OSGi project it may be better to not use the PDE. You can also create bundles using the maven bundle plugin. It analyzes the imports you do and creates the manifest automatically. In most cases this is much better than the PDE manifest first way and it works better with maven.

See: http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/02/15/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+1+-+Installation+and+First+application

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a target Platform defined, and I didn't think that I would need to add each dependency to it... but come to think of it - that makes sense. But I still don't understand why my "plug-in" manifest can't just use the interaces in the jar fetched by maven. What does this "maven-bundle" plugin do, that makes this work? It can't _only_ generate the manifest - because I already have a manifest and it doesn't work.

Comment: Also I just realized that I can't really put it into the Target Platform, because it doesn't an update site or anything of that sort. So I'll essentially have to download the jar, placed it into the directory, and then place that directory in my Target Runtime... which kind of negates the whole maven advantage. Just thinking...

Comment: Basically you have two steps in the process. One step is the creation of the Manifest file. This is where the maven bundle plugin can help. The second step is the dependency resolution inside the OSGi framework. In the PDE eclipse does this using the target platform. If you do not use the PDE (like in my tutorial) then the OSGi dependency resolution only happens in the OSGi server like in my case Apache Karaf. Of course this still means you have to provide all dependencies in Karaf but Karaf can use maven dependencies so it matches better.

Comment: @drozzy: If you use [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) as local Maven repository proxy, you can use the [p2 plugin](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Nexus/Nexus+OSGi+Experimental+Features+-+P2+Repository+Plugin) to make everything in your Maven repository also available as a p2 repository.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Thanks, but I work in a company, and I need only free and no-license tools.

Comment: @drozzy: Nexus OSS and the plugin are both available for free under the [Eclipse Public License](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925638/can-epl-eclipse-public-licence-be-used-in-commercial-context).

Comment: @BjörnPollex Cool. So basically I could host bundles in maven repository? And browse them? cool. Do you know if this works with bndtools?

Comment: @drozzy: Nexus also is an OBR repository, so it does work with bndtools.

Comment: @BjörnPollex It seems like it is only supported by Nexus Pro (and not the free version): http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/osgi-sect-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

just add an export statement in that packages manifest file,remember for every import there should be export[enter link description here](http://blog.christianposta.com/osgi/understanding-how-osgi-bundles-get-resolved-part-i/)